# returning template class from member function

Tags: c++, templates

I'm trying to implement engine using ECS pattern and i want to have entity class template that would be used to represent in-game objects:

```
template<typename...components>
class entity
{
    //...
};
```

and entity_manager class that would manage lifetime of entities:

```
class entity_manager
{
public:
    template<typename...components>
    entity<components...> create_entity<components...>();
    
    bool destroy_entity(entity_id id);
    //...
}
```

When i try to compile it i get following error with gcc:

```
error: expected initializer before ‘<’ token
   15 |     entity<components...> create_entity<components...>();
      |                                        ^
```

and with clang:

```
error: function template partial specialization is not allowed
    entity<components...> create_entity<components...>();
                          ^            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

My question is why it is not working what would be possible solution?

Comment: In the function declaration `create_entity<components...>();` --> `create_entity();` otherwise it looks like a specialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't put a template argument list after the name of a function in its declaration.

Simply:

```
template<typename...components>
entity<components...> create_entity();
```